# Trying to Create a VisualForce Page that has a Lookup Field displayed as a picklist that is filtered by the previous field

Tags: visualforce, picklist, lookup-filter

I have a visual force page that I am trying to create an availability checker based on the city that the person resides in Italy. But when checking the page it does not filter and just shows me none since it is not picking up field values from the page.

**Here is the VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Italy_Fibre__c" extensions= "ItalyFibreExtension" showHeader="false" >  
       <apex:form id="Fibre_Availability">  
         <apex:pageBlock title="" mode="edit">  
           <apex:pageBlockButtons>  
             <apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;"/> 
           </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Fibre" columns="1"> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!Italy_Fibre__c.PROVINCIA__c}" rendered="True" required="true" id="PROVINCIA" />
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 

       <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Italy_Fibre__c.fields.Comune__c.label}" for="pLabel"/>  
         <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">  
         <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>  
    <apex:actionRegion>  
         <apex:selectList id="ComunePicklist" value="{!Italy_Fibre__c.Comune__c }" size="1" rendered="true">  
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!ComuneOptions}"/>  
         </apex:selectList>  
  </apex:actionRegion>  
 </apex:outputPanel>  
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >   
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Italy_Fibre__c.fields.SGU__c.label}" for="pLabel"/>  
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">  
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>  
   <apex:actionRegion >  
      <apex:selectList id="SGUPicklist" value="{!Italy_Fibre__c.SGU__c }" size="1" rendered="true">  
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!SGUOptions}"/>  
   </apex:selectList>  
 </apex:actionRegion>  
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**Here is the Extension**

```
    public class ItalyFibreExtension {  
    private final ApexPages.standardController controller;  
    private final Italy_Fibre__c obj;

    public ItalyFibreExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {  
        this.controller = stdController;  
        this.obj = (Italy_Fibre__c)stdController.getRecord();  
    }  

    public SelectOption[] getComuneOptions() {  
        SelectOption[] Comunes = new SelectOption[]{};  
        Comunes.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));  
        for (COMUNE__c c : [select id, name from COMUNE__c where PROVINCIA__c = :obj.PROVINCIA__c order by name]) { 
            COMUNEs.add(new SelectOption(c.id, c.name ));  
        }  
        return Comunes;  
    }
        public SelectOption[] getSGUOptions() {  
        SelectOption[] SGUS = new SelectOption[]{};  
        SGUS.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));  
        for (SGU__c s : [select id, name from SGU__c where Comune__r.name = :obj.Comune__c order by name]) { 
            SGUs.add(new SelectOption(s.id, s.name ));  
        }  
        return SGUS;  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rerender the child picklist to get filtered value

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Italy_Fibre__c.PROVINCIA__c}" rendered="True" required="true" id="PROVINCIA" >
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Fibre_Availability" />
</apex:inputField>
```

When you rerender the form your getter method will get called again and now they will give you updated value.